# MS-Script query unable to get working or to run

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to create a query to show the top 24 most-viewed pages by joining 3 tables.

But, I am having trouble getting it to work. Either it has an issue with the use of `UNION`, `JOIN` or a part of the written function/script, in general.

The tables are:

```
+---------------+
| dbo_Good_URLs |
+---------------+
| Url           |
| HTTPAlias     |
| PortalID      |
| page_title    |
+---------------+
```

```
+-----------------+
| dbo_vw_GoodURLs |
+-----------------+
| URL             |
| PortalID        |
| HTTPAlias       |
| Title           |
+-----------------+
```

```
+-----------------------+
| dbo_analytics_history |
+-----------------------+
| URL                   |
| PortalId              |
| HTTPAlias             |
| Page_Title            |
| Report_Month          |
| Report_Year           |
| Pageviews             |
| Unique_Pageviews      |
| Entrances             |
| Total_Time_on_Page    |
| Bounces               |
| Exits                 |
| Avg_Time_on_Page      |
| Bounce_Rate           |
| Exit_Rate             |
+-----------------------+
```

[image]

I've tried to use an `IIF(Is Null(**)` And I've looked through to script itself to see why `UNION` and `JOIN` seem to not work and I can't seem to figure it out.

I've been playing around with this all week and it's just not coming to me.

```sql
SELECT TOP 24 dbo_Good_URLs.Url, Nz(dbo_analytics_history.Pageviews, 0) AS Total_Pageviews,
Nz(dbo_analytics_history.Pageviews, 0) AS Month1
FROM (SELECT Url FROM dbo_Good_URLs WHERE HTTPAlias IN ('x.org', 'ab.x.org'))
 UNION 
SELECT Url FROM dbo_vw_GoodURLs WHERE dbo_Good_URLs.HTTPAlias IN ('x.org', 'ab.x.org')
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo_analytics_history
ON dbo_Good_URLs.Url = dbo_analytics_history.URL AND dbo_analytics_history.HTTPAlias IN ('x.org', 'ab.x.org') AND dbo_analytics_history.Report_Month = 10
GROUP BY dbo_Good_URLs.Url, dbo_analytics_history.Pageviews
ORDER BY Nz(dbo_analytics_history.Pageviews, 0) DESC;
```

The result that I am looking for is for it to show the top 24 pages viewed for the month of October(I.e. month 10)

Comment: What is the error message you get?

Comment: Syntax error in union query

Answer (score 0):

I would hazard a guess that you're actually looking for something like the following:

```sql
select top 24 q.url, nz(a.pageviews, 0) as Total_Pageviews, nz(a.pageviews, 0) as Month1
from 
    (
        select dbo_good_urls.url from dbo_good_urls 
        where dbo_good_urls.httpalias in ('x.org', 'ab.x.org')
        union 
        select dbo_vw_goodurls.url from dbo_vw_goodurls 
        where dbo_vw_goodurls.httpalias in ('semcog.org', 'loggedin.semcog.org')
    ) q
    left join dbo_analytics_history a on q.url = a.url
)
where
    a.report_month is null or a.report_month = 10
order by 
    nz(a.pageviews, 0) desc;
```

Here, the target URLs are selected by the two unioned subqueries, with the result of such union left joined to your `dbo_analytics_history` table on the `url` field.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am still getting the syntax error with union query message with this.

Comment: @rosey What specifically is the error message you are receiving?